# Query to get the highest IP from a list of IP addresses

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a list of IP addresses in a table along with the clients hostname, grouped using a foriegn key field as so:

```
ReqID, Hostname, IPAddress
4, Server01, 192.168.10.5
4, Server02, 192.168.10.6
4, Server10, 192.168.10.7
4, Server15, 192.168.10.8
4, Server18, 192.168.10.9
4, Server23, 192.168.10.10
```

The IP's are stored as varchars.

I want to get the highest allocated IP for a specific ReqID. How would I do this?

**EDIT: I have SQL 2005**

Comment: how do you store the IP Address? as Varchar?

Comment: @johntotetwoo - See second to last line.

Comment: With a.b.c.d being an IP address, and function y = f(a,b,c,d)  for f := d * 256^0 + c * 256^1+b*256^2+a*256^3, and bigint being an int64, store y as bigint, then you can simply do a MAX(y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert the IP into number using this function:

```
--Author: Faisal Khan (http://www.stardeveloper.com)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIPToLong](@IP varchar(15))
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Long bigint
    SET @Long = CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 4)) * 256 * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 3)) * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 2)) * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 1))

    RETURN (@Long)
END
```

(from [here](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/convert-ip-address-to-long/))

and then

```
select reqid, max([dbo].ConvertIPToLong(IPAddress)) as maxIP
from your_table
group by reqID
```

**EDIT:** From the same source you can use

```
-- Author: Faisal Khan (http://www.stardeveloper.com)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertLongToIP](@Long bigint)
RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IP varchar(15)
    DECLARE @TempLong bigint
    DECLARE @Temp bigint

    SET @TempLong = @Long
    SET @Temp = @TempLong / (256 * 256 * 256)
    SET @TempLong = @TempLong - (@Temp * 256 * 256 * 256)
    SET @IP = CONVERT(varchar(3), @Temp) + '.'
    SET @Temp = @TempLong / (256 * 256)
    SET @TempLong = @TempLong - (@Temp * 256 * 256)
    SET @IP = @IP + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Temp) + '.'
    SET @Temp = @TempLong / 256
    SET @TempLong = @TempLong - (@Temp * 256)
    SET @IP = @IP + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Temp) + '.'
    SET @Temp = @TempLong
    SET @TempLong = @TempLong - @Temp
    SET @IP = @IP + CONVERT(varchar(3), @Temp)

    RETURN (@IP)
END
```

and the query will be

```
select reqid, [dbo].ConvertLongToIP(max([dbo].ConvertIPToLong(IPAddress))) as maxIP
from your_table
group by reqID
```

Comment: +1 Should work in 2005 though you probably need another function to map it back.

Comment: The convert function looks good, but I need to get the actual highest IP back for a specific ReqID. Your query will return the ReqID and a Long representation of the highest IP.

Comment: @TomPickles at the link indicated you have the function ConvertLongToIP() :)

Comment: @FlorinGhita thanks. The webpage makes for interesting reading. I think I'll amend my DB to store IP's as bigint's instead as I'm still in the development phase. The conversion functions will still be of use.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT ReqID, 
       REPLACE(MAX(CAST('/'+ IPAddress +'/' AS HIERARCHYID)).ToString(), '/', '') 
FROM   your_table 
GROUP  BY ReqID
```

For SQL Server 2005 can't think of a better approach than [@Florin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240751/73226) though it is missing a function to round trip back.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIPToString](@IP bigint)
RETURNS varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT LTRIM(I3) + '.'+ LTRIM(J3) + '.' + LTRIM(J2) + '.' + LTRIM(J1)
        FROM (SELECT @IP/256, @IP % 256) T1(I1, J1)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT I1/256, I1%256) T2(I2, J2)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT I2/256, I2%256) T3(I3, J3)
    )
END
```